# Building a board game, not sure what to use for the "computer"

Tags: soc

My brothers and I are building an interactive board game that will require a central device to keep track of the number of players,  player resources, turns, location, etc. I have an idea of how I'm going to build this program wise (some form of bare bones linux).

However hardware wise I don't know where to start. It would preferably need to be smaller and on the inexpensive side because this is a prototype and we hope to produce the game, along with that, battery powered is a must. It doesn't need to be some god machine, just something that can keep track of letters and numbers and spit them out onto a screen.

I think I will be fine on sourcing the buttons and screens, but if you have suggestion for those I'm open to it as well.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: For a prototype you could probably do this using an Arduino and an LCD screen. When you move to production you'll probably want to get rid of the Arduino board and just use the Atmel microcontroller that is at the heart of the Arduino board.

Comment: First check which kind of display you want. That one is the expensive part, especially in small volumes. Also think about whether you need a touch screen or not.

Comment: If the game is interactive, there probably are some requirements for system response time, display lag, etc., which would determine the necessary computing power of the "computer". Are there any requirements like that?

Comment: Why do you think you want to use Linux? In any case, it's far too early in the process to be thinking about details like which CPU to use. You first need to nail down all of the details concerning exactly how the users will interact with this device (input and output). If there's going to be a screen, how much and what kind of information does it need to display? How frequently must it be updated?

Comment: How does the device get input from the players, such as pushbuttons, a touchscreen, or perhaps sensing activity on the board itself? Only after you have specified the *functionality* of the device in considerable detail is it appropriate to consider the implementation technology.

Comment: Did you think about writing this as an app to run in an Android device? You would have all the HW you need for "free"

Answer (score 2):

For a prototype you could probably do this using an Arduino and an LCD screen. When you move to production you'll probably want to get rid of the Arduino board and just use the Atmel microcontroller that is at the heart of the Arduino board. The Arduino can be programmed using standard libraries through a simple IDE (Integrated Development Environment) and when you're ready for production you simply pop the chip out of the Arduino board and plug it in to a custom PCB. Using the standard Arduino libraries could make this very easy.

Comment: No need to waste time and money in designing HW for this when everyone has one or more smartphones at home

Comment: Then it's not really to do with electronic engineering anymore. Also why not use a raspberry pi?

Comment: @Bradman175 When the OP says "computer" I think all he really needs is something to do the tracking and displaying. For that all you need is a microcontroller. I think using an actual computer like the RPi would be overkill

Answer (score -3):

Back before Don Lancaster introduced The TV Typewriter in Radio Electronics magazine, I designed and built a tic-tac-toe machine using 70 SSI TTL. The clock rate, running thru the 4 X 10 flipflops of the algorithm-scan, was 10Hz or so, thus the 4 second worst case response gave a sense of "thinking" which the users liked.

The long-term state was 9 cells of 3-NAND-gates, with open/machine/human as owner.

Depending on how much you wish to learn about hardware, you might use a pile of EEPROMs for program store (to be updated over USB from some PC) with program counter(parallel loadable for implementing JUMPS) to step thru your behavior.
And some Static RAM for the names and locations and object behaviors in your world.

After 6 months of that, Intel would be hiring you.

In later years, processing data from automated measurement systems before pushing the data to tape-recorders, I developed customer micro-coded instruction sets that used 8-bit counters as the ProgramCounter, to access control bytes from MonolithicMemory 256word of 8bits one-time-programmable memories. Using a 6800 would have been the better solution, but management did not approve that, so I simply designed custom CPUs with customer instruction sets.

Key? Work thru *all* the operations needed, figure which operations should be in hardware, then supply the bit-patterns out of memory to launch the timed operations. Just like any computer functions today.

Comment: I don't... Get... Wha??

Comment: @brad You've never developed custom CPUs?

Comment: Really no point since microcontrollers exist. In addition, they are much cheaper, less prone to problems, and take up way less space.